# Cakephp 2.5 Postlink hidding the model atribute name at the url

Tags: cakephp

I am using a cakephp 2.5 postlink method inside a view file :

```
$tableRow['Model.modelatribute'] = $this->Form->postLink(
                    $data['Vehicle']['plate'],
                    array('controller'=>'somecontroller',
                      'action' => 'somemethod',
                      'Model.modelatribute' => base64_encode($data['Vehicle']['plate'])
                    ),
                    array('confirm' => 'Look at  vehicle '.$data['Vehicle']['plate'])
                );
```

I would like not to show the model atribute name on the url bar. After clicking on the link and being redirected, the url shows :

```
somemethod/Model.modelatribute:vSpEeTIweQ%3D%3D
```

Can i hide the model atribute name, using postlink method o cakephp 2.5 ?

Thank´s in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to pass the value of `Model.modelatribute` as a parameter, just leave off Model.modelatribute in your [routing array](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/glossary.html#term-routing-array). If you want to pass the value without occouring in the url you can use the [data option](https://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-FormHelper.html#_postLink) of postLink.

```
echo $this->Form->postLink(
    $data['Vehicle']['plate'],
    array(
        'controller'=>'somecontroller',
        'action' => 'somemethod',
        base64_encode($data['Vehicle']['plate']) // Routing array without modelname
    ),
    array(
        'confirm' => 'Look at  vehicle '.$data['Vehicle']['plate'],
        'data' => array(
            // Data option of postLink method
            'Model.modelatribute' => base64_encode($data['Vehicle']['plate'])
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, *you* put in there. If you don't want it to be there simply don't put it in the URL. You can alternatively [put it into the body of the POST request](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.View.Helper.FormHelper.html#_postLink).

If you're concerned that people can use the model name for something and you want to hide it for that reason, then it is a very bad approach called [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity). Instead you want to ensure that you validate that only values you want are passed and processed. So check your incoming data, always, from everywhere.